# How to reutilize canvas objects using fabric js by switching to different apps

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am able to draw shapes on canvas perfectly . But my use case is , on my front end UI has bottom navigation. Means , I have to show case

- tab1 -> rect, line
- tab2-> line
- tab3->rect

- so If I switch to tab2 , I have show only tab2 associated shapes have been drawn.
- If I switch to tab3 , I have to show only tab3 associated shapes have been drawn.
  etc .

What I have done was ,

```
  var objects = this.getCanvasObjects();
          var clonedObjs = Array.from(objects);
```

the above "objects" contained all shapes tab1,tab2 , etc

```
 this.removeAllCanvasObjects();
```

As I copied entire canvasobjects into clonedObjs , I am removing all objects.

//I had put some custom **tabId** before drawing a shape

```
  clonedObjs.foreach((value,index)=>{
    if(value["tabId"]==currId){
               // i will draw what ever the shape it may be .
                   drawRect;
           }
   })
```

but with above approach background canvas object is getting removed as I am removing all canvas objects before going to draw .

But How can I reuse canvas objects , by switching between tabs. Any answers are more appreciated .

Comment: This is the wrong way to ask a question on stack overflow. The question is generic and not entirely code related.
Said so, why can't you have a canvas per tab?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi thanks for the response .Sure I will improve my questioning skills on stackoverflow. Coming to ur question,  only one canvas is there on the UI , in the bottom , we have tabs. so if I draw any shape on canvas which is related to tab1 , and if I switch to tab2 , what ever shape I drew related tab1 have to be removed . If I again switch to tab1 , I have to show what ever shape I had drawn on tab1. same thing will be applicable for remaining tabs.

Comment: I m suggesting you  have 3 canvases, and when tabbing you hide/show the relative tab canvas.